# Error while creating module fatal error: Class 'Mage_Cart_Insuranceupsell_Helper_Data' not found in src/app/Mage.php on line 555

Tags: magento-1.9

I try to create new module. I add src/app/etc/modules/Cart_InsuranceUpsell.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cart_InsuranceUpsell>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Cart_InsuranceUpsell>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I add src/app/code/local/Cart/InsuranceUpsell/etc/config.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cart_InsuranceUpsell>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Cart_InsuranceUpsell>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <cart_insurance_upspell>
                <class>Cart_InsuranceUpsell_Helper</class>
            </cart_insurance_upspell>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

System.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <cart translate="label" module="cart_insuranceupsell">
            <label>Insurance Upsell</label>
            <sort_order>10000</sort_order>
        </cart>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <cart_insuranceupsell translate="label" module="cart_insuranceupsell">
            <label>Config</label>
            <tab>cart</tab>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <configuration translate="label">
                    <label>Insurance Upsell Configuration</label>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enabled translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        </enabled>
                        <discount_rate translate="label">
                            <label>Discount rate </label>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </discount_rate>
                        <insuranceupsell_checkbox_popup_text translate="label">
                            <label>Insurance upsell checkbox popup text</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </insuranceupsell_checkbox_popup_text>
                        <insuranceupsell_checkbox_text translate="label">
                            <label>Insurance upsell checkbox text</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </insuranceupsell_checkbox_text>
                    </fields>
                </configuration>
            </groups>
        </cart_insuranceupsell>
    </sections>
</config>
```

And helper :

```
<?php

class Cart_Insuranceupsell_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

When I load page system -> configuration I see Class

> 'Mage_Cart_Insuranceupsell_Helper_Data' not found in
>   /var/www/hosts/mage-composer/src/app/Mage.php on line 555

Call stack :

[image]

Doesn't help(
EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <cart_insurance_upsell translate="label" module="cart_insurance_upspell">
            <label>Insurance Upsell</label>
            <sort_order>10000</sort_order>
        </cart_insurance_upsell>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <cart_insurance_upsell translate="label" module="cart_insurance_upspell">
            <label>Config</label>
            <tab>cart_insurance_upsell</tab>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <configuration translate="label">
                    <label>Insurance Upsell Configuration</label>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enabled translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        </enabled>
                        <discount_rate translate="label">
                            <label>Discount rate </label>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </discount_rate>
                        <insuranceupsell_checkbox_popup_text translate="label">
                            <label>Insurance upsell checkbox popup text</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </insuranceupsell_checkbox_popup_text>
                        <insuranceupsell_checkbox_text translate="label">
                            <label>Insurance upsell checkbox text</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </insuranceupsell_checkbox_text>
                    </fields>
                </configuration>
            </groups>
        </cart_insurance_upsell>
    </sections>
</config>
```

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: Do you need helper class?

Comment: @SukumarGorai no, but error with the word helper, that why I insert it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This module declaration

```
<cart_insuranceupsell translate="label" module="cart_insuranceupsell">
```

... has to match defined helper alias ...

```
    <helpers>
        <cart_insurance_upspell>
            <class>Cart_InsuranceUpsell_Helper</class>
        </cart_insurance_upspell>
    </helpers>
```

Please try to change

```
<cart_insuranceupsell translate="label" module="cart_insuranceupsell">
```

to

```
<cart_insuranceupsell translate="label" module="cart_insurance_upspell">
```

Comment: It's doesn't help. Edit question

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич Its still wrong in `<tabs>` node.

Comment: changed, cleaned the cache did not help(
edit

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич is call stack still the same?

Comment: I added last edit

Comment: why i need to cart_insurance_upspell?

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич `module=[NAME]` in system.xml has to match alias in config.xml. Just to test ... remove all `module=...` in system.xml flush cash and try again.

Comment: with out `module=...` is working, but if I click it I have 404

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич  404 normally comes from not defined ACL roles. For the helper pls make sure spelling is correct and files are in correct folder.